Tips for golfing in Emmental
What general tips do you have for golfing in Emmental? It is a self-modifying language defined by a meta-circular interpreter, so I wonder if there are tips for golfing for this esoteric programming language.
I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Emmental. (i.e. "remove comments" isn't an answer - Emmental doesn't even have this feature) Also, please one tip per answer.
